# How can I snapshot test a Vue SFC page in Nuxt that only contains a layout using jest

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

How can I snapshot test a Vue SFC page in Nuxt that only contains a layout using jest.
For example:

```html
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'some-layout-name'
};
</script>
```

I get an error because it is lacking the template part, I could not make it generate a snapshot in snapshot testing in jest.

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
      
      found in
      
      ---> <Anonymous>
             <Root>

      at warn (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621:15)
      at mountComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4024:9)
      at VueComponent.Object.<anonymous>.Vue.$mount (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8392:10)
      at init (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3112:13)
      at createComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5958:9)
      at createElm (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5905:9)
      at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6455:7)
      at VueComponent.Vue._update (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3933:19)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you have a `<template>` element in your Single File Component SFC.

Example.

```html
<template>
  <div/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'some-layout-name'
};
</script>
```

N.B. Without the `<template>` element in your SFC, you'll continue to get the error experienced.

```
render function or template not defined in the component.
```

Comment: Is there any workarounds that does not involve adding a template?

Comment: Not what I know of if you're using SingleFile components. 

If you're just wanting the JavaScript side, you could simply use `.js` and omit the `<script>` tag.